# How to compile PHP into opcode and run it in production environment?

Tags: php, opcode

Note,it's not what the recent hiphop project of facebook,I just want to convert it into `opcode`,not `c/c++`.

Is there a solution yet?

A demo is always the best!

Comment: If you want to convert PHP code to directly executable code, I would just use HipHop.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is a [PHP Accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator)

However, these tools compile to [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode), not [opcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) as requested.

Answer (score 3):

@Dolph's answer is correct: There's no way to compile PHP directly to `opcode`. The PHP binary itself compiles PHP code to PHP `bytecode` and then executes those bytecodes. The best you can expect it to cache the compiled bytecode with a PHP accelerator. Other than that, the only route would be to use a langugae which does compile to opcode, which is the aim of the Facebook hiphop project.

For some additional information:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Usage
2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bcompiler.php
3. http://eaccelerator.net/
4. http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/zend-optimizer
5. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php