# Compilation of PHP- to op-code and having the opcode executed

Tags: php

PHP is usually compiled to opcode by the Zend engine on execution time.

To skip the compiling every time one can use an opcode cache like APC to save the opcode in shared memory and reuse it.

Okay, now it seems that there is **no** solution yet for just compiling the PHP to opcode and using that. Similar to how you use Java.

**But why?** I am wondering about that b/c this is a quite obvious idea, so I guess there is a reason for this.

**EDIT**:

the core question is this:

*wouldn't make PHP-compilation make opcode-caching superfluous?*

The only "reason" against it would be that you couldn't just fix something on the live-system ... which is anyway bad bad bad practice.

Comment: there is even a better aproach by facebook ... see Hip Hop for PHP https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php

Comment: [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) already has this to support closed-source feeliable projects?

Comment: easy ... my question is not about converting PHP to C++. It's about opcode.

Comment: we just have to wait for PHP 6

Comment: You can use only opcode, there's a setting in APC for that, it's called apc.stat - if set to 1, APC won't check whether there's a PHP file associated with the parsed opcode. That way, you can parse entire project into opcode and basically delete the files. But as everything, it's not the best idea to do that.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417831/how-to-compile-php-into-opcode-and-run-it-in-production-environment.  Short answer: basically you can't.  If not, then that questions need an update as well.

Comment: interesting! but why do you think this wouldn't be a good idea? so it would be possible to compile PHP to opcode with apc_bin_dumpfile() and then have it executed with APC and your setting?

Comment: @Sheepy - you can, but it's not advisable.

Comment: @Sheepy: it's not a duplicate. My question is not just aiming at the "How" but also at the "Why". Also the other question is more aiming at the APC-solution, mine is aiming at compiling to opcode.

Comment: @N.B. why is it not advisable?

Comment: @Raffael1984 - There three reasons I can think of. First, opcode is not really maintainable. Second, opcode changes with php version.  They are harder to deploy, too.

Comment: @Raffael1984 - as anything, every method has its positives and negatives and you need to know what might go wrong and what's the time penalty you'll face to fix the issue. Thing is you can lose the cache (reboot, power outage etc) and you have to rebuild it. You can modify a single feature of your project and you need to rebuild the cache. You can automate this process if you have enough knowledge to create the scripts for it, but as you can see - every time you change something you need to manually force cache rebuild.

Comment: However, there IS the option of having only opcode on the server, it just isn't the most elegant solution. As Sheepy said, opcode changes with every PHP version. If you can afford to spend some time setting everything up, you can make your server run only the opcode from cache without it ever having the source php files. If that's what you want - you can have it :)

Comment: @Sheepy: [1] the code itself is maintainable enough, if it's maintained, then you compile it (happens in Java, C++, C, etc all the time) / [2] so? php-code also depends on PHP-versions ... / [3] it's very easy to deploy, you just copy it.

Comment: If you think it's worth your effort - go ahead and use the feature, it's there. Just be aware of possible bad scenarios. Can you afford not having your app up if something happens to the cache?

Comment: @N.B. okay, then your scepticism is more aiming at the APC-hack. I can see that. But a well-crafted PHP>opcode>engine solution is anything but "not elegant". It would be very elegant actually. Though you are mentioning that the opcode-definition is changing with PHP-version. of course if that happens for increments of the n (l.m.n) - bugfixes -  then this would indeed be a pain in the ass. but for increments of m and l one has anyway to think about how this affects the code!

Comment: I just don't think that deploying ONLY opcode cache is viable. First, performance gain is negligible and second - there is a possibility that your app can stop working, even if that possibility is very small and shouldn't happen - why risk the downtime? Bottlenecks of webapps aren't underlying languages, it's usually I/O caused by the storage engine (RDBMS). I guess it all boils down to what you want to achieve in the end. You won't get turbo boost of your app if you deploy opcode only, that's for sure.

Comment: @N.B. again you are referring to a "cache" - I am not talking about a cache - I am interested in compiling to opcode and executing opcode. It just happens that mentioning opcode always leads to APC. But actually APC is what I don't want to use! I want to code the PHP, then compile it, then deploy it.

Comment: @Raffael1984 - ok, my fault I didn't get you immediately. I don't really know how to force ZendEngine to execute opcode if it's not cached by APC, which is why I'm talking about APC. I also don't know how to "store" the opcode without APC effectively (I'm not talking about obtaining the opcode) so I used APC in my comments. In the end, it is what you were talking about - use opcode only, deploy opcode only and execute opcode only - currently it's done by using apc.stat = 0 and parsing the whole project after which you remove the original php files.

Comment: @N.B. I kinda think that there are intentional obstacles set up by Zend to keep control over PHP. Cause as soon as the opcode-layer is unveiled then anybody could write alternative engines and do lots of funny stuff that makes it harder for Zend to capitalize on PHP.

Comment: @Raffael1984 - it's not like PHP isn't opensource, so it kinda defeats your comment about Zend keeping control over PHP. With sufficient knowledge, you can hack PHP and ZE itself to suit your needs. Of course, this process isn't trivial.

Comment: @N.B. it is open-source for historical reasons. the business model of Zend does not embrace the open-source idea, not at all! their products aren't open-source. Zend has been founded by two PHP-savvy businessmen who capitalize on PHP. And b/c PHP cannot be turned into closed source anymore, it is instead implemented in a way that makes it harder to really unleash the power of open source.

Comment: @Raffael1984 - we could discuss all day about politics, but what it boils down to that there's PHP, there's a PHP compiler, there's the opcode cache (built in into 5.4 version which by default runs even faster) and there are alternatives to PHP. We're never forced to walk with one dog, there's always a choice and the right tool for the job :)

Comment: so how about your pointless comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've given one reason against it.

Another very important one is that if you separate the compile from the runtime both in terms of the time at which each occur but also in terms of the hardware where it runs, you quickly run into complex dependency problems - what happens when you try to run opcode generated by PHP 5.1 on a PHP 5.3 runtime?

It also makes debugging of code harder - since the debugger has to map the opcode back to the source code.

But a very important question you don't seem to have asked let alone answered is what is the benefit of pre-generating the opcode?

Would compiling the opcode prior to runtime have a significant benefit over caching the opcode? The difference would be un-measurably small.

Certainly the raison d'etre for [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) is that *natively* compiled PHP code [runs faster](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/17/drupal-hiphop-for-php-vs-apc-benchmark/) than PHP with opcode caching at the expense of some functionality. But that's something quite different.

Do you think that having only the opcodes on the server improves the security (by obscurity)?

Comment: okay, well, it seems like the fluctuation of opcode-definition without downward compatibility is the main obstacle. Though debugging is no reason, cause you debug on the dev-environment, without pre-compiling then. I am not talking about security.

Comment: So you're suggesting it's OK to test/debug using different software than you use in production?

Comment: well, a C++-developer won't debug machine code either ... am I right or am I right?